# Where is mdadm event log on Centos 7?

Tags: centos7, mdadm

I have a centos 7.2 server with software raid1 setup using mdadm.

This morning I've noticed mdadm is "checking" array, but I have no idea why. There is no mail for root and I can't find any logfile of mdadm events. I have tried grepping `/var/log/messages` and `journalctl`, but I didn't find anything there either. There doesn't seem to be anything related to raid in `/var/log/`.

What is the default location of mdadm log in Centos?

```
# mdadm.conf written out by anaconda
MAILADDR root
AUTO +imsm +1.x -all
ARRAY /dev/md/0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=2abdcc7e:8940f8ca:d704759d:e17533da
ARRAY /dev/md/1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=a6018d37:ec249eb7:084e037d:c3500c57
ARRAY /dev/md/2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=5134811d:50c6e923:6432b424:a47c132d
ARRAY /dev/md/3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=fcbbd4b0:2989bd1e:11fe20d0:37009306
ARRAY /dev/md/4 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=ad36eae9:8c5f0405:bd81613a:513a1602
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a disk fails, kernel logs the following to /var/log/messages

```
Oct 19 19:24:33 r5452 kernel: md/raid1:md2: Disk failure on sdb3, disabling device.#012md/raid1:md2: Operation continuing on 1 devices.
```

The error messages are also sent to the virtual console. On a headless server, it is possible to view them:

```
setterm -dump -file /tmp/screen.dump
cat /tmp/screen.dump
```

and example message will look like:

```
[  428.850203] md/raid1:md2: Disk failure on sdb3, disabling device.
[  428.850203] md/raid1:md2: Operation continuing on 1 devices.
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because it doesn't exist.

You can see the status of an array by interpreting its metadata and drive states, or by using some kind of monitoring to do that for you, such as daemonized mdadm or a simple Nagios system.

In the case of `mdadm`, it is possible to use that as a monitoring tool. Take this for example:

`# mdadm --monitor --daemonise --mail=root@localhost /dev/md2`

This will mail root when events occur, and will run in the background. This could be run at each startup, but is a very basic solution. It may be enough for you.

You can poll a RAID array for details via the `mdadm` tool manually. A general status of your array will be output when using `# mdadm --detail /dev/md0`. Alternatively, you may check the status of your arrays by viewing the output of the mdstat file: `# cat /proc/mdstat`.

The metadata information of individual disks that constitute an array can be see using the `--examine` flag like so:

`# mdadm --examine /dev/sda2`

Finally, if you suspect a drive is bad because it shows errors when running `--detail` on an array, it is typically prudent to check its SMART status, in addition to the status of the rest of your drives to see if everything else is in good shape. The following command will print all details of your first disk, and should be run for every disk that makes your RAID array:

`# smartctl -a /dev/sda`

Comment: Any idea why mdadm is not logging it's activity?

Comment: Have you instructed it to? It does not run as a monitoring daemon by default, as using mdadm for a monitoring daemon is considered fairly weak. It would be better to monitor it along with the rest of your infrastructrure with a tool such as Nagios (or whatever you use in your organization). Additionally, in order to use the `MAILADDR user@domain.com` directive, you must place a full e-mail in that field *and have an SMTP server of some kind running to process it*.

Comment: The following may help in addition to what I've put: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7001034